# Fixed point of random permutation

Tags: probability, fixed-points

Suppose we have a random permutation of the integers from $1$ to $100$.
What is the expected value and variance of $X-Y$, where $X$ is the number of fixed points (numbers which are at the same place before and after permutation) and $Y$ is the number of non-fixed points.

Comment: It is very hard to understand the question. Please give at least an example. (And show us the own efforts.) For instance, if we work in the space of permutations of six symbols, $S(6)$, and $s\in S(6)$ is $\binom{123456}{126345}$, then $X(s)=2$ and $Y(s)=4$? So $X(s)$ is the number of fixed points of $s$, and $Y(s)=6-X(s)$? So we only need to know the expectation and the variance of $X$?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be more specific in the future problems.

Comment: Your explanations are exactly what I want. Could you please give further derivations of the expectation and the variance of X-Y? Thanks!

Comment: Indicator method is helpful here. For a randomly chosen permutation $\pi$, represent $X = X(\pi)$ by $$X(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^{100}\mathbf{1}_{\{\pi(i)=i\}}$$. This helps you figure out the question. For instance, you may try computing $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{100}\mathbb{P}(\pi(i)=i).$$